# Knockout foreach to Partial View

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, foreach

I have a view which loads products with bootstrap:

```
@model Store.WebUI.Models.ProductsListViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Custom/listViewModel.js">
</script>

@foreach (var p in Model.Products)
{
    @Html.Partial("ProductSummary", p)
}

<div class="btn-group pull-right">
    @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", 
        new {page = x, category = Model.CurrentCategory}))
</div>
```

And a partial view:

```
@model Store.Domain.Entities.Product
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Custom/listViewModel.js">
</script>

<div class="well">
    <h3>
        <strong>@Model.Name</strong>
        <span class="pull-right label label-
primary">@Model.Price.ToString("C")</span>
    </h3>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Cart"))
    {
        <div class="pull-right">
            @Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.ProductId)
            @Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to 
cart"/>
        </div>
    }

    <span class="lead">@Model.Description</span>
</div>
```

However I want it with Knockout via foreach. Is there a way to get element from "foreach" in knockout, and send it to Partial View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing to remember with knockoutjs is where it is being executed, the client browser. The ASP.NET MVC Partial View is being rendered on the server and then gets delivered to the browser.

For knockout to work as it should, you deliver the data and the view template to the browser as separate parts then let the client do the rendering.

**Edit**
This is how I would start approaching it.  You are basically implementing the partial view as a html template and a javascript viewmodel

```js
function formatCurrency(value) {
  return "$" + value.toFixed(2);
}

var productData = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Big Toy 1",
    price: 15.99,
    description: "This is a big toy",
    returnUrl: "<bigtoyUrl>"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Big Toy 2",
    price: 16.99,
    description: "This is also a big toy",
    returnUrl: "<bigtoyUrl>"
  }, {
    id: 3,
    name: "Big Toy 3",
    price: 17.99,
    description: "Wow another big toy",
    returnUrl: "<bigtoyUrl>"
  }
];


var Product = function(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.productId = ko.observable(data.id || 0);
  self.name = ko.observable(data.name || "");
  self.description = ko.observable(data.description || "");
  self.returnUrl = ko.observable(data.returnUrl || "");
  self.price = ko.observable(data.price || 0);
  self.price.display = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return "$" + self.price().toFixed(2);
  });
  self.addToCart = function() {
    
  }

};

var Cart = function() {

};


var PageViewModel = function(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.productList = ko.observableArray(data.products.map(function(item) {
    return new Product(item);
  }));
  self.cart = ko.observableArray();
  self.addToCart = function(product) {
    self.cart.push(product);
  };


}


ko.applyBindings(new PageViewModel({
  products: productData
}));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<!-- ko foreach: productList -->
<div class="well">
  <h3>
    <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>
    <span class="pull-right label label-primary" data-bind="text: price.display"></span>
  </h3>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to cart" data-bind="click: $parent.addToCart" />
  </div>
  <span class="lead" data-bind="text: description"></span>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<h3>Cart</h3>
<ul data-bind="foreach: cart">
  <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So will it be better for me to ditch the partial view here? I understand what you mean, but I am pretty new to both ASP.NET MVC, jQuery and Knockout, so with this specific case I know how to do it in the view and I am a bit confused as to how can this all be done with partial view.

Comment: If you want to use knockout then yes I would suggest ditching the partial view.  for your specific example have a look at http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html